# ¿Que diferencias existen entre las distintas formas de definir un DEFAULT 0?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
ALTER TABLE compras.factura_gasto ADD COLUMN m_excento numeric(36,2);
ALTER TABLE compras.factura_gasto ALTER COLUMN m_excento SET DEFAULT 0::numeric;
```

Mi duda es: En SET DEFAULT ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre tener `SET DEFAULT 0` y `SET DEFAULT 0::numeric` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninguna diferencia significativa. Particularmente la notación `0::numeric` es un "casteo" explícito de un literal, que de por sí ya es considerado numérico, tal vez tendría más sentido hacer `'0'::numeric`, pero de cualquier forma lo que vale siempre es la definición de la columna, en tu caso `numeric(36,2)`, por lo que el motor tratará de "castear" cualquier valor a ese tipo de dato, con cualquiera de estas formas el resultado es el mismo:

```
ALTER TABLE dummy ALTER COLUMN m_excento SET DEFAULT 0
ALTER TABLE dummy ALTER COLUMN m_excento SET DEFAULT '0'
ALTER TABLE dummy ALTER COLUMN m_excento SET DEFAULT '0'::numeric
```

Comment: Es decir ¿Seria "castear" el valor dos veces?

Comment: Si, es un forma bastante sencilla pero efectiva de definirlo.

Comment: Quisiera preguntar sobre otro caso parecido.
¿Existe diferencia entre `timestamp(0) without time zone` y `timestamp without time zone`?

Comment: Posiblemente sí, pero te la debo por ahora.. Es buena para una nueva pregunta.